# Live Wallpaper with Transparent Preferences Activity

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, preferenceactivity

I have a WallpaperService which runs on the Home Screen.
When I set the Preferences Activity for my wallpaper service to transparent with:
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

you can see the wallpaper in the background when the preferences window is open. I want to make it so that the wallpaper reacts to touches with the preferences window open in the same way it reacts when the home screen is touched. However, the onTouchEvent() from my WallpaperService is not called when I touch with the preferences window open.

I would like to make it so both the preferences window and the underlying wallpaper receive touch events.

If that is not possible, I would like to make it so that the preferences window copies its touch events and sends it to the wallpaper service, but I am unsure how to access the WallpaperService or the Wallpaper Engine from inside the preferences activity.

Comment: The issue is that you have two activities: one is yours, and it shows your preferences; the other belongs to the home screen, and it shows your live wallpaper. In general, I know of no way to forward touch events from one activity to another. The only possible solution I can suggest is that you implement your preference screen the way a launcher application would implement a home screen and have your live wallpaper as the background of your own Activity. I don't know how that actually works, but it's something to think about.